# CVS command to get brief history of repository

Tags: version-control, cvs

I am using following command to get a brief history of the CVS repository.

```
cvs -d :pserver:*User*:*Password*@*Repo* rlog -N -d "*StartDate* < *EndDate*"  *Module*
```

This works just fine except for one small problem. It lists all tags created on each file in that repository. I want the tag info, but I only want the tags that are created in the date range specified. How do I change this command to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way to do that natively with the rlog command.  Faced with this problem, I would write a Perl script to parse the output of the command, correlate the tags to the date range that I want and print them.

Another solution would be to parse the ,v files directly, but I haven't found any robust libraries for doing that.  I prefer Perl for that type of task, and the parsing modules don't seem to be very high quality.